# Copying large files to WebDAV share lets overflow the file system

Tags: debian, rsync, backup, davfs2

From my internet provider, I got 100GB WebDAV cloud storage. I wanted to use this to store a remote backup of my pictures. Unfortunatelly, copying the 75GB into the cloud lets repeatedly overflow my root filesystem , i.e. `/var/cache`.

This is **Debian Bullseye**.

```
mount -t davfs https://sd2dav.1und1.de /media/dav
nohup rsync --partial -avp /home/user/Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib /media/dav/Bilder/ &
```

On the next morning (after reboot)

```
$ cat nohup..out

sending incremental file list
Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib
rsync: [receiver] write failed on "/media/dav/Bilder/Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib": No space left on d>rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(378) [receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)

$ df -h
Dateisystem                 Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                         1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /dev
tmpfs                        388M    1,2M  387M    1% /run
/dev/mapper/server--vg-root   33G     31G   37M  100% /
tmpfs                        1,9G    4,0K  1,9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
/dev/mapper/server--vg-data  6,9T    6,2T  455G   94% /data
/dev/sda1                    234M    162M   60M   74% /boot
/tmpfs                        388M     32K  388M    1% /run/user/1000
```

which was caused by `/var/cache`. This happens always, not just when copying this specific file but when trying to backup directly from my windows machine into this directory (over SMB). It really seems to be a regular problem.

My upload is **45 Mbits/s**, rsync should respect this.

I don't understand why this always floods my root filesystem. If the cloud storage was unmounted during copying, it should flood /media/dav, right? But there is nothing.

Is DAV just not stable neough for this kind of usage?

Answer (score 1):

According to your `df -h` output, `/media/dav` didn't get mounted...It was actually your rootfs `/` that got filled up (because /media/dav is just a sub-dir of / unless you mount another fs on it).

You should make the `rsync` run conditional on the mount succeeding.  e.g. something like this:

```
mount -t davfs https://sd2dav.1und1.de /media/dav &&
  nohup rsync --partial -avp /home/user/Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib /media/dav/Bilder/ &
```

or:

```
if mount -t davfs https://sd2dav.1und1.de /media/dav ; then
  nohup rsync --partial -avp /home/user/Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib /media/dav/Bilder/ &
fi
```

You may want to do even more checks.  e.g. if you know that a file called "davfs-is-mounted" will be in /media/dav if the davfs is mounted, but not otherwise then:

```
if mount -t davfs https://sd2dav.1und1.de /media/dav ; then
  if [ -e /media/dav/davfs-is-mounted ] ; then
    nohup rsync --partial -avp /home/user/Bilder_Cloud_full_b1_s1_v1.tib /media/dav/Bilder/ &
  fi
fi
```

Comment: BTW, you may want to put the entire command sequence into a script file, and add `set -x` (for verbose debug/trace output) **AND** `set -e` (so that it exits on the first error - e.g. if the mount fails).   Then run the script with both stdout and stderr redirected to a log file.   That will log everything, not just the rsync run by nohup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the DAV volume was mounted because I checked before mount (empty dir) and after5 (files already on the DAV volume). So, it got unmounted during the process. How could I catch this?